# 'hardwareAccelerated' error in Android

Tags: android, android-manifest, hardware-acceleration

When I use 'hardwareAccelerated' in AndroidManifest.xml then this type of error message shown.
Please help me, Why this type of error generated.

```
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'hardwareAccelerated' in package 'android'
```

Comment: Could you paste your AndroidManifest.xml here?  It seems like you may have the attribute in an incorrect location.

Comment: What is your build target?

Comment: Maybe you're testing on a device that doesn't support Hardware Acceleration?  Or on that device, you have hardware acceleration turned off.